# CentOS keeps losing its localtime setting?

Tags: centos, timezone, time

I'm running an extremely typical CentOS 6.5 server at DigitalOcean.  As part of the site setup, I've changed /etc/localtime to something appropriate for me:

```
rm /etc/localtime
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
```

This works fine, except somebody/something is resetting it:  I'll check back in with the server at some random (I think) point, and find that my link has been replaced with the original localtime file, putting the server back in UTC.  I've looked in /etc/cron* on the chance that there's a script in there doing it, but I can't find anything.  Has anyone else run into this before?  Thanks!

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of that question, although it is related. This question is in regards to "What is resetting /etc/localtime automatically?", which is a different topic then "Changing Timezone, Centos Apache server".

Comment: @StefanLasiewski That is also answered in that question.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but it's the top result in google for "yum-cron update changed timezone"

Answer (score 9):

In order to (correctly) change the timezone of your system you will need to access the file [/etc/sysconfig/clock](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-clock.html) and edit `ZONE=<filename>` value, for example

`ZONE="Europe/Belgrade"`

Then proceed with linking the zoneinfo file to /etc/localtime

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Belgrade /etc/localtime
```

(if the question is what is resetting timezone info, it might be [yum update](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=2085))

Comment: Looks very promising -- I've made the change and will see what happens in the next couple of days (translation: I'll come back in a couple of days and accept the answer if all's well).  Thanks!

Comment: Was this the correct answer?

Comment: This solved my issue where yum-cron update reset the time zone to UTC.